# Use string format to format number but don't change value

Tags: python

How can I get a string same as input number?

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(1559628846)
'1559628846.000000'
```

expect 1559628846

```
>>> '{:}'.format(1559628846.0001234)
'1559628846.0001235'
```

expect 1559628846.0001234

```
>>> '{:}'.format(0.000001)
'1e-06'
```

expect 0.000001

My real problem is how to concat a string and any number without change the number?

```
>>> '{},{}'.format('Hi', 1559628846.0001234)
'Hi,1559628846.0001235'
```

expect 'Hi,1559628846.000123'

Comment: Floating point values are approximations.

Comment: The actual value of the number is basically never exactly what you wrote in the code. `1559628846.0001234` is an approximate representation, which gets turned into the nearest possible floating point number as soon as it's parsed. Alternatively, if you write a number as `1e-06` in your source code, it's never stored like this, and you cannot tell afterwards that it was written as `1e-06` and not `0.0000001` instead. Numbers don't have formats; they're just values. If you are interested in exactly unchanging representations, use strings.

Comment: Closest solution I can think of is [`numpy.format_float_positional`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html). But it requires a dependency, just for one method.

Comment: You could use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) package for this kind of accurate representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating point number is displayed on the screen in base 10, but stored on the computer as base 2.  There isn't always an exact representation of the base 2 number the computer is using.  [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) has a great article on the nuances of that.

That explains the rounding error.  As for why python doesn't remember the exact number of digits you were using, it's because storing a floating point number is more efficient than storing the string you started with.  Run this test to see the difference:

```
>>> import sys
>>> fnum = 12345.67890
>>> snum = '12345.67890'
>>> sys.getsizeof(fnum)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(snum)
36
>>>
```

In programming, you almost never care about how the number was entered, you just store the floating point representation and make your display layer show the user a pleasing representation that depends on your use case.  If you really care what was originally entered, you'll have to store it as a string, not a float.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the input number as a string. For instance:

```
print('{},{}'.format('Hi','1559628846.0001234'))
```

Output: `Hi,1559628846.0001234`

Otherwise, it will always approximate it.

Another option would be to round it to a certain digit, which is not in the order of the accuracy:

```
i = round(1559628846.0001234, 5)
print('{},{}'.format('Hi',i))
```

Output: `Hi,1559628846.00012`